# Prepared query is not returning expected result trying to find user

Tags: php, prepare

I have one result when I do this in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT password, block FROM jml_users WHERE username = "user01"
```

However in my PHP code the script does not find my user. Am I doing something wrong with `$stmt->bind_param("s", $unsafe_user);`?

I also tried `$stmt->bind_param("s", "user01");` with no luck.

```
<?
include("dbinfo.php");
$unsafe_user = "user01";
$mysqli = new mysqli($loginURL, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $database);

LoginCheck();

// Kill connection 
$thread_id = $mysqli->thread_id;    // determine our thread id 
$mysqli->kill($thread_id);
$mysqli->close();

function LoginCheck()
{
    global $mysqli, $unsafe_user;   

    //Perpare Statement.    
    //if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password, block FROM jml_users WHERE (username) VALUES (?)")) // this returns false for some reason
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password, block FROM jml_users WHERE username = ?")) //works, still safe form sql injection?
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $unsafe_user);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($dbpw, $bdblock);

        if($stmt->num_rows == 0)
        {
            echo "could not find user";
        }
        // Found user
        else
        {
            echo "found user";
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Statement creation did not succeed";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Bluestrike. Thanks for marking the question as solved, but it is not necessary here. Instead, add the solution you used (or ask a commenter to do so, so they get the points) and then tick it to remove it from unanswered lists. You may tick questions you answer yourself if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query you commented out is invalid MYSQL syntax. That type of syntax is for inserts.

Also num_rows won't work with prepared statements unless you use `$stmt->store_result();` after `$stmt->execute();`.

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php#71988) answer in the documentation.